# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-compat: 25.0.1.?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to find out what is the exact issue when I add the dependencies.

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.jetradarmobile:android-snowfall:1.1.2'
}
```

I get the above error

```
 my Gradle(Project)


     buildscript {
         repositories {
             jcenter()
         }
         dependencies {
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
         }
     }
     allprojects {
         repositories {
             jcenter() {
                 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
             }
         }
     }
     task clean(type: Delete) {
         delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

#### My Gradle(App)

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
         compileSdkVersion 24
         buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
         defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.animationbook.animationbook"
             minSdkVersion 15
             targetSdkVersion 24
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
             testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         }
         buildTypes {
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
         }
     }
     dependencies {
         compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
             exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
         })
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
         debugCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
         compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
         compile 'com.github.jetradarmobile:android-snowfall:1.1.2'
     }
```

How can the error be solved?

Comment: try rebuilding your project again

Comment: rebuilding cannot solve the issue

Answer (score 5):

It's happen because your dependency `com.github.jetradarmobile:android-snowfall:1.1.2` has  `compileSdkVersion 25`, `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` & `com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1`.

So you need to change `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0`, `buildToolsVersion` to `25.0.1` and `com.android.support:design:25.1.0`.

If you don't want to change your `buildToolsVersion` than you can use module of it and change modules `buildToolsVersion`.

Comment: if we have multiple library dependencies,the one library dependncy has different compile sdk version to that of Other one.In that Scenario how the problem is Resolved???

Comment: multiple library dependencies has different compile sdk version which is available. in your case dependency has compile sdk version which is not installed that's why you have two option either you install that version or change dependency's compile version.

Comment: changing the Dependency compile version needs to install that version build tool Or not????

Answer (score 3):

change the `buildToolsVersion to 25.0.1` and add dependency  `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'`

And also change `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'`

Comment: it seems like no, try this

Comment: that means we have to install the buildtools version of 25.0.1

Comment: compile 'com.github.jetradarmobile:android-snowfall:1.1.2' needs 25.0.0 build tool and if i update to 25.0.2 build tool.Does it make any problem????

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and what I did to solve it was Update "Google Repository" and "Android Support repository" in the Android SDK Manager.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I will do that @Enrique

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

> I just updated all the support lib versions and error was gone!!!